# Force Azure Outbound Traffic via a Single Public IP

Tags: firewall, azure, azure-networking, wide-area-network

### Question

Is there a way, when using an Azure VWan with outbound traffic directed via the VWan's firewall, to ensure all outbound traffic breaks out via the same, single public IP address.  Note: I'm open to workarounds.

### Context

We're in the process of migrating our Azure hosted infrastructure from a collection of peered VNets where outbound traffic from any VM goes via the MS backbone on an arbitrarily assigned IP, to using a VWan with firewall where all outbound traffic is routed via the firewall.

When we want to add new inbound services (e.g. routing FTPS connections from public IPs to their backend VMs) we use one of the public IPs associated with the firewall, add a DNat rule to map this incoming public IP & port to the backend's private IP and port.  However, this means that each time we have a new inbound requirement using the same public port, we have to create a new public IP on the firewall.

Each public IP added has repercussions:

- Various whitelists and SPF records must be updated to include the new IP.  <s>We can work around this a bit by getting a [Public IP Prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-address-prefix) to reserve a range or addresses, then we can use this CIDR for our whitelists, even if we're not yet making use of all the IPs in this range.  This works well until we hit the limit of this range, so relies on good forecasting/overprovisioning.</s>  **Updated:** Prefixes are not an option either as we're using a secure virtual hub; rather we'd have to just overprovision assigned public IPs, then whitelist each specific IP assigned.
- Some protocols (e.g FTPS in passive mode) don't play well as soon as there's more than 1 public IP.  I.e. Am FTP client within our network establishes a (command) connection with an external FTPS server, it's given a port to use for the data channel, establishes a new (data) connection on this new port, and Azure assigns this new connection to a different IP (as it's a new connection it sees no need to be consistent) and the external server sees a data channel claiming to relate to the authenticated command channel, but coming from a different IP, so rejects this new connection as suspicious.  There's currently a [request/suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/59931e39-8426-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789) to allow pinning outbound connections to a specific IP, but there's no indication of this being on the roadmap.

I dislike scenarios like these; as they create gotchas; e.g. someone working on some unrelated task (e.g. publishing a new FTPS service for one of our systems) may inadvertently cause our emails to be flagged as spam and variuos other integrations to fail because of introducing a new IP.

These issues could be resolved if we could direct all outbound traffic via a single public IP.

Whilst I understand that if an Azure Firewall has multiple Public IPs assigned there's currently no way to route traffic via one of these; is there a workaround; e.g. set the next hop for outbound traffic from this firewall to a second firewall which has a single public IP configured?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible with a route table and a virtual network gateway.

Comment: Thanks @Turdie; could you expand on what you mean here?  My understanding of virtual network gateways is that they're used to provide connectivity between private networks (i.e. via VPN or ExpressRoute), rather than related to connectivity from a private network in Azure out to the public internet; so I'm missing something in my current understanding of how this would work.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You can connect a VPN gateway to your vwan and then with the right udr/routing rules you can force the outbound traffic to one single public ip

Comment: How does the VPN Gateway fit into this?  In case relevant; I'm discussing routing traffic that originates from our servers within our VNets in Azure, rather than from some remote site/user.  Apologies if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to explain this to you further than I already did. But let me try a bit for the last time. But you need to have some basic knowledge how routing in Azure works. A Vnet is linked to an UDR, in the UDR you specify that outbound traffic (by a default 0.0.0.0 route for example) is send to the VPN gateway, the VPN gateway has a public ip and send it to the internet. The VPN gateway resides in the virtual wan

Comment: But there are lot of design choices in Azure virtual wan, and if you are going to use an expressroute it all changes. Also keep in mind that public ip is subject to change, because it's a Microsoft owned ip.. Sorry j just read that's not possible when using an azure firewall in the vwan also, it's on the roadmap. Sorry